# Call mvnw.cmd from a .bat file

Tags: maven, batch-file

I am creating a container in docker using the below command.I need to use the below command from a .bat file when I execute the command from the command line it runs but does not work with the batch file.What am I doing wrong here.

Batch File

```
call mvnw.cmd spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=service
```

Error:

> 'mvnw.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: add it to the `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not know where the `mvnw.cmd` is, either use an environment variable, with relative path, or use an absolute path, or navigate to the directory, before running the command.